# Can't get Bootstrap list item contents to align vertically properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a list with items that contain a label, a button and a toggle. I can't get the divs to vertically align properly, since they are of different heights.

The code looks like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item form-inline">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Pin:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: Layout]

And [BOOTPLY DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/q6ZEkPpOt7)

Thanks!

Comment: Please recreate the problem in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) and add it to your post.

Comment: What do you mean by "vertically align properly"... Looks like they align-top correctly.

Comment: I'd like to align middle, so that all elements are on the same "axis"

Comment: Can't align middle floated columns, you'd have to change the way the grid works to do that to either display:table/table-cell or inline-block and that's a lot of extra css. The .h3 class around the second column is the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your label is an `h3` element, which has a greater height than the toggle and button. One solution would be to wrap the controls in `div.h3` as well:

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Pin:</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="h3">
      <input checked="" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" type="checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CF31L3Eaf1)

Note that using `<h3>` instead of `<div class="h3">` would work as well as far as the layout is concerned, but that would be semantically incorrect because the buttons are not headings.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to see this result. You can add `line-height` to your class and solve it.

[**HERE IS DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/y2v8uulG7d)

UPDATE:
For the changeble font sizes, you can use this example.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/79x2a/26/)**

Comment: Looks good, but I wonder if there's a fix that would work for any size text.